# Remove duplicates leaving at least one with highest parameter from group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following schema:

```
+--+------+-----+----+
|id|device|token|cash|
+--+------+-----+----+
```

column `device` is unique and `token` is not unique and null by default.

What i want to achieve is to set all duplicate `token` values to default (null) leaving only one with highest `cash`. If duplicates have same `cash` leave first one.

I have heard about cursor, but it seems that it can be done with usual query.

I have tried following SELECT only to see if im right about my thought how to achieve this, but it seems im wrong.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    db.table
WHERE
    db.table.token NOT IN (SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                MAX(db.table.balance)
            FROM
                db.table
            GROUP BY db.table.balance) temp
            )
```

For example:
This table after query

```
+-----+---------+--------+-------+
| id  |  device | token  |   cash|
+-----+---------+--------+-------+
| 1   | dev_1   | tkn_1  |  3    |
| 2   | dev_2   | tkn_1  |  10   |
| 3   | dev_3   | tkn_2  |  10   |
| 4   | dev_4   | tkn_2  |  14   |
| 5   | dev_5   | tkn_3  |  10   |
| 6   | dev_6   | null   |  10   |
| 7   | dev_7   | null   |  10   |
| 8   | dev_8   | tkn_4  |  11   |
| 8   | dev_8   | tkn_4  |  11   |
| 8   | dev_8   | tkn_5  |  11   |
+-----+---------+--------+-------+
```

should be:

```
+-----+---------+--------+-------+
| id  |  device | token  |   cash|
+-----+---------+--------+-------+
| 1   | dev_1   | null   |  3    |
| 2   | dev_2   | tkn_1  |  10   |
| 3   | dev_3   | null   |  10   |
| 4   | dev_4   | tkn_2  |  14   |
| 5   | dev_5   | tkn_3  |  10   |
| 6   | dev_6   | null   |  10   |
| 7   | dev_7   | null   |  10   |
| 8   | dev_8   | tkn_4  |  11   |
| 8   | dev_8   | null   |  11   |
| 8   | dev_8   | tkn_5  |  15   |
+-----+---------+--------+-------+
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET token = NULL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT * FROM yourTable) t2
              WHERE t2.token = t1.token AND
                    t2.cash > t1.cash);
```

### Demo

Note that this answer assumes that there would never be a tie for two token records having the same highest cash amount.

Comment: thank you for you response, but in table i have a lot of same token records with same balance (mostly 0)

Answer (score 0):

To set exactly one row in the even of duplicates on the maximum cash, use the `id`:

```
update t join
       (select tt.*,
               (select t3.id
                from t t3
                where t3.token = tt.token
                order by t3.cash desc, id desc
               ) as max_cash_id
        from t tt
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id and t.id < tt.max_cash_id
    set token = null;
```